# Are there any websites that I can gamble (with fiat/real money, or cryptocurrencies) in chess?

Tags: online-chess

Where can I play chess online for fiat/real money?

Comment: I'd be surprised if they exist, because it would soon become a contest of "who has the most powerful computer".

Comment: Cheating is already such a huge problem on sites with no money interaction, i.e., chess.com, chess24.com, lichess.org. Why would these problems not be infinitely worse with a gambling website?

Comment: Since chess tournaments have been forced to cancel or do events online these days, you can probably play in one of those (hosted by ICC I believe) and compete for real money. There are also occasional qualifiers into real money events that goes on in various sites - usually only titled players will win any money, because there is money involved.

Answer (score 2):

playchess.com has its own currency called [ducats](https://en.chessbase.com/post/ducats-and-playchess).
1 ducat = 0.1 euro
You will have a hard time finding an opponent willing to play for ducats though.